# Visualizing RGB openVDB volumes

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I have 3D-volumes where each voxel is associated to a RGBA color, I use the following code to convert numpy arrays (of shape [128, 128, 128, 4], RGBA) to openVDB files:

```
import pyopenvdb as vdb

def convert_to_openvdb_file(fname: pathlib.Path, openvdb_dir: pathlib.Path):

    arr = np.load(fname)

    rgb = 255. * arr[..., :3]
    rgb_grid = vdb.Vec3SGrid()
    rgb_grid.copyFromArray(rgb)
    rgb_grid.name = 'color'

    a = arr[..., 3].astype(bool)
    a_grid = vdb.BoolGrid()
    a_grid.copyFromArray(a)
    a_grid.name = 'density'

    output_dir = openvdb_dir.joinpath(*fname.parts[-3:-1])
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    seq_id = int(fname.stem)
    output_fname = output_dir.joinpath("{:04d}".format(seq_id)).with_suffix('.vdb')
    vdb.write(str(output_fname), grids=[rgb_grid, a_grid])
```

Conceptually, I use a `Vec3SGrid` for the RGB and a `BoolGrid` for the alpha channel. Loading this into Blender yields the following (correct) view in solid mode:
[image]

However, I cannot manager to define a shader that properly renders the colors even if I specify 'color' as the color attribute. So far, I have tried Cycles (normal + experimental mode) and Eevee, but to no avail. I use Blender version 3.1.
[image]

**Question**: Why can't the colors be properly rendered?

Comment: Have you find a solution? Can you attach an example file?